# Azure - multiple websites dyamically based on subdomain

Tags: git, azure, azure-web-app-service, vhosts, subdomain

We are using Azure to host our website. We have Git set up with a custom hook for each commit and branch, so we can see a snapshot of a particular commit (or the latest version of a given branch):

- http://commit-1234.commits.example.com/
- http://some-feature.branches.example.com/

At the moment we are managing our staging environment through an Apache VM because vhosts makes it dead easy - we just dump the code for a given commit (or branch) into an appropriately folder. For the above:

- /htdocs/commits/commit-1234/
- /htdocs/branches/some-feature/

Can this be done in Azure Websites (now Web Apps)? How would we create some dynamic rule so IIS maps, say, "commit-1234" to the folder /webroot/commit-1234/ and uses that as the root for relative paths (e.g., server-side includes)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two solid options for live testing deployment brances: Deployment Slots & Virtual Applications

**[Deployment Slots](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-staged-publishing/)**

You can create a deployment slot for your site which allows for some cool features like AB testing (some small amount of traffic would go to that slot). Since you pay per instance of App Service and not per Web App, you don't get charged anything extra, and then you have clean environments (like maybe if one of the changes does a database upgrade, you can use a different schema without any silly hacks). You'd then have a url name like `{{sitename}}-{{commit}}.azurewebsites.net`. You could set up each slot manually or get a script going. Wouldn't be too hard to get a [WebJob running listening for your GitHub Hooks](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions#webhooks) and [then provisioning the staging slot](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/arm-template-deployment/). You'll want to read up on Kudu (Web App's open source deployment engine) and how [Deployment Hooks](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deployment-hooks) work.

**[Virtual Applications](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure/#virtual-applications-and-directories)**

You can deploy virtual applications and map them with IIS, similar to how you are doing it with Apache. You can checkout [Tom's Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2014/09/22/deploying-multiple-virtual-directories-to-a-single-azure-website.aspx) where he covers the details of actually setting up the virtual application. I think this ends up being more difficult and it still requires manual steps. I only mention it because the result is pretty close to what you stated. You can map each virtual directory to a specific URI (e.g `/{{commit}}/`).

FYI - I'm a PM on the Azure Web Apps team. I think the first example is pretty interesting. I'd be will being to help out and turn that into a blog post.

Comment: The challenge with deployment slots is that they are quite limited in number (nil, 5 or 20 depending on service level, if I've correctly understood the documentation). They also don't stay live for a long time, which is handy if you want to create permalinks back to a version.

Comment: You can also just use plain old Web Apps and migrate the App Settings. Still get the advantage of not being charged extra (if they are on the same App Service).

Answer (score 0):

When you configure Git integration for each Azure website/app endpoint, you can choose the branch.

From the documentation: "In the Continous Deployment blade, choose the organization, project, and branch you want to deploy from. When you're done, click OK."

Source: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-publish-source-control/

Hope that helps! :)

- Shahed